# Open Search BulkProcessor retries config not working

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, resthighlevelclient

What is the right way to configure the retries of bulk api? I am having some of the batches fail with 429 and 504 which could be retried.

Here is how the bulk processor is setup

```
    public BulkProcessor createBulkProcessor() {

        BiConsumer<BulkRequest, ActionListener<BulkResponse>> bulkAsyncRunner =
                (request, bulkListener) -> {

                    request.timeout(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(bulkApiConfig.timeOutSecs));
                    client.bulkAsync(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, bulkListener);
                };

        BulkProcessor.Builder builder = BulkProcessor.builder(bulkAsyncRunner, new BulkProcessorListener());

                if(bulkApiConfig.payloadSizeMb!=null){
                    builder.setBulkSize(new ByteSizeValue(bulkApiConfig.payloadSizeMb, ByteSizeUnit.MB));
                }else{
                    builder.setBulkActions(bulkApiConfig.batchSize);
                }
                builder.setConcurrentRequests(bulkApiConfig.concurrentRequests)
                .setBackoffPolicy(
                        BackoffPolicy.exponentialBackoff(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(bulkApiConfig.retryInitialDelayMs),
                                bulkApiConfig.retries));
        return builder.build();
    }
```

```
public class BulkProcessorListener implements BulkProcessor.Listener {

    @Override
    public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, Throwable failure) {
       //log error
   }
}
```

However afterBulk() logs just once and not as many times as configured in backOffPolicy

Using

```
   implementation group: 'org.opensearch.client', name: 'opensearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '2.7.0'
```

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. I do not think the BulkProcessor supports retries in these cases (I've never actually seen it successfully retry anything). In any case, the bulk processor and the high level rest client in general aren't supported anymore. There is an issue to reimplement it on the non-deprecated java api. https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-java/issues/181